# Eigenvalues of $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix in $M(\mathbb{R})$. I'd like to know if there is an exact formula for the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. Clearly, it's false that $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Does $A$ have real (as opposed to complex) entries?

Comment: Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1& 0\end{pmatrix}$. It is normal, with eigenvalues $\pm i$, so squares are $-1$, when $A^TA$ has eigenvalues $1$

Comment: $A$ is real matrix.

Comment: It is, real matrices can have complex eigenvalues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Much of this is made much easier to see if you know about the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).  My answers below rely heavily on this.

---

For your first statement, any non-normal matrix provides a counterexample.  In fact, we have the following theorem:

> Let $A$ be a square matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_k$.  Let $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ (which are all positive).
> Then
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^n |\lambda_k|^2 \leq  \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k
> $$
> and $A$ is normal if and only if
> $
> \sigma_k  = |\lambda_k|^2
> $ for each $k$.

The proof of your second statement (by the spectral theorem) is as follows:

Because $A$ is normal, there exists a unitary matrix $U$ and diagonal matrix $D$ (each with complex entries) such that
$A = UDU^*$
where $M^* = \overline{M^T}$ denotes the conjugate-transpose, AKA the adjoint of a complex matrix.  Note that
$$
D = \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\&\ddots \\&& \lambda_n}
$$
where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.
We then have
$$
A^TA = A^*A = (UDU^*)^*UDU^* = 
UD^*DU^* = U \pmatrix{|\lambda_1|^2\\ & \ddots \\ && |\lambda_n|^2}U^*
$$
Thus, the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are $|\lambda_k|^2$.

---

As noted in the comments on the question, there is no formula for the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ that only uses the eigenvalues of $A$. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4090967/81360) addresses the relationship between these quantities in general.

Comment: You need to square the **absolute value**. That what those "$|\cdot|$"s are there for.

Comment: Note that $U^*U=I$ doesn't imply $U^TU=I$.

Comment: To your edit: $A$ is real, so $A^T = \overline{A^T} = A^*$.

Comment: I suppose that you mean "if $A$ is skew symmetric, any of its eigenvalues is $i \lambda$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb R$".  Yes, this is true.  So, what of it?

Answer (score 7):

Counterexample:

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{eig} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &= \{0,1\} \\
\operatorname{eig} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} &= \{0,2\} \\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That is not a normal matrix

Comment: @uranix As best I can tell there are two parts to the question. First, is it true that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T A$? Second, is the previous statement true if we assume that $A$ is normal? Arkamis' answer addresses the first question. Hence my +1.

Comment: It is ok to give a example of non normal matrix.

Answer (score 6):

A real normal matrix is the matrix that satisfies $AA^T = A^T A$. That's what wiki says on normal matrices

> Among complex matrices, all unitary, Hermitian, and skew-Hermitian matrices are normal.

Skew-Hermitan matrices are promising for counterexample, since their eigenvalues are purely imaginary. Real skew-Hermitan matrix is just a skew-symmetrical one.

Let $A$ be the skew-symmetrical matrix. Consider eigenvector $x$ of $A$. He have
$$
A^TA x = -A^2 x = -\lambda^2 x
$$